# Javascript menu and box display

Tags: javascript, html

Apparently there is an issue with my code that I can't find, because the code isn't running when I click on the menu links. What I'm creating is basically a menu that dynamically changes the content of an adjacent box, and the appearance of the menu links depending on which menu link is clicked. Here is as simplified version of my code:

HTML:

```
<td class="instructioncells" colspan="1" width="25%">
<a href="#" onclick="helpmenu(showid)" class="link" id="dashboardlink" style="color:      
black; text-decoration: none;">The My Marketing Dashboard</a>
<div style="height:4px;">&nbsp;</div>
<a href="#" onclick="helpmenu(showid)" class="link" id="methodlink">Selecting a    
Method</a>
</td>
<td width="75%" style="vertical-align: top;">

<div id="mymarketingdashboard" style="display: block;">
<div class="font4" style="text-align: center">
The My Marketing Dashboard
</div>
</div>

<div id="selectmethod" style="display: none;">
<div class="font4" style="text-align: center">
Selecting a Method
</div>
</div>

</td>
```

Javascript:

```
function helpmenu(showid) 
{
    var showdashboard = document.getElementById("mymarketingdashboard");
    var showmethod = document.getElementById("selectmethod");

    var mymarketing = document.getElementById("dashboardlink");
    var method = document.getElementById("methodlink");

    if (showid == "dashboardlink") 
    {
        showdashboard.style.display = "block";
        mymarketing.style.color = "black";
        mymarketing.style.textDecoration = "none";
        showmethod.style.display = "none";
        method.style.color = "#2C3A7F";
        method.style.textDecoration = "underline";
    }

    if (showid == "methodlink") 
    {
        showdashboard.style.display = "none";
        mymarketing.style.color = "#2C3A7F";
        mymarketing.style.textDecoration = "underline";
        showmethod.style.display = "block";
        method.style.color = "black";
        method.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
```

Any help on finding why the code isn't running as is would be awesome. Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried validating your code with tools like the W3C validation service and jslint or jshint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to your code:

**Javascript**:

```
helpmenu = function (showid) 
{
    var showdashboard = document.getElementById("mymarketingdashboard");
    var showmethod = document.getElementById("selectmethod");

    var mymarketing = document.getElementById("dashboardlink");
    var method = document.getElementById("methodlink");

    if (showid == "dashboardlink") 
    {
        showdashboard.style.display = "block";
        mymarketing.style.color = "black";
        mymarketing.style.textDecoration = "none";
        showmethod.style.display = "none";
        method.style.color = "#2C3A7F";
        method.style.textDecoration = "underline";
    }
    if (showid == "methodlink") {
        showdashboard.style.display = "none";
        mymarketing.style.color = "#2C3A7F";
        mymarketing.style.textDecoration = "underline";
        showmethod.style.display = "block";
        method.style.color = "black";
        method.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
}
```

**Markup**:

```
<table><tr><td class="instructioncells" colspan="1" width="25%">
<a href="#" onclick="helpmenu(this.id)" class="link" id="dashboardlink" style="color:      
black; text-decoration: none;">The My Marketing Dashboard</a>
<div style="height:4px;">&nbsp;</div>
<a href="#" onclick="helpmenu(this.id)" class="link" id="methodlink">Selecting a    
Method</a>
</td>
<td width="75%" style="vertical-align: top;">

<div id="mymarketingdashboard" style="display: block;">
<div class="font4" style="text-align: center">
The My Marketing Dashboard
</div>
</div>

<div id="selectmethod" style="display: none;">
<div class="font4" style="text-align: center">
Selecting a Method
</div>
</div>

    </td></tr></table>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/UxQD9/1/

I simply pass the id of the clicked anchor to the `helpmenu` function.

Comment: Aw! this.id. What a dumb mistake. Thanks for helping me out with that.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes it is hard to see little things like that. If this solved your issue please mark as answered :)

Comment: Of course. Wouldn't allow me to for a few more minutes. Thanks again.

Comment: just a followup question so I don't have to repost all this code. If you dont' know I will. When javascript updates the style properties of these links, my general CSS a:hover color swap effect for links stops working for the menu links. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry I was in a meeting. I imagine that it is because you are setting inline styles which takes priority over the css class. If you want to avoid this, instead of changing the style, create a css class with all of your css styles and toggle between one class and the other.